# Tracking down forgotten brokerage account

Tags: stocks, employee-stock-options, paycheck

My friend worked at Home Depot for several years during the early 1980s and participated in the employee stock investment program with 5% of his paycheck.

His employment there ended abruptly upon the replacement of the floor manager with whom he did not get along.

My friend had always assumed that he forfeit his stock contributions and moved on, only to mentioning it to me in the context of  a story he was telling me.

How would one go about locating forgotten long-dormant investment accounts such as this?

Comment: State dormant accounts rules.

Answer (score 1):

A company as large as Home Depot will have a fairly robust Human Resources department and would probably be able to steer you in the right direction: odds are they know the name of the brokerage and other particulars. I did some googling around, their # is  (1-866-698-4347).

Different states have different rules about how long an institution can have assets abandoned before turning them over to the state. [California, as an example, has an abandoned property search site that you can use](http://sco.ca.gov/upd.html).

That being said, I had some penny stocks sitting in a brokerage account I never touched for about 20 years and when I finally logged back in there they were, still sitting there.

Comment: Thanks for the information. You kinda left me hanging there with your penny stock story....  =)